# I am trying to learn how to get the sum from a list of numbers in a file that represent currency in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the sum of a list of numbers from a file that represents currency amounts. I could not get it to work so I created an array inside my code and got it working for my assignment that way; but I still want to know how to program this myself for future reference.
Here is a copy of the code that I did write and the values of the file Sales.txt are:

```
1245.67
1189.55
1098.72
1456.88
2109.34
1987.55
1872.36
```

Here is the copy of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Lab7._2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // ReadScore method
        private void ReadSales(List<decimal> salesList)
        {
            try
            {
                // Open File Sales.txt
                StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");

                // Read the sales into the list.
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    salesList.Add(decimal.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine()));
                }

                // Close the file
                inputFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Display an error message
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        } 

        // DisplaySales method displaying to ListBox
        private void DisplaySales(List<decimal> salesList)
        {
            foreach (decimal sales in salesList)
            {
                runningTotalListBox.Items.Add(sales);
            }
        }
        // The average method returns the average of the values
        private double Average(List<decimal> salesList)
        {
            decimal total = 0;  //Accumulator
            double average; // to hold the average

            // Calculate the total of the sales
            foreach (decimal sales in salesList)
            {
                total += sales;
            }

            // Calculate the average of the scores.
            average = (double)total / salesList.Count;


            // Return average.
            return average;
        }




        private void calButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double averageSales; // To hold the average sales

            // Create a list to hold the sales
            List<decimal> salesList = new List<decimal>();

            // create decimal array
            double[] units = { 1245.67, 1189.55, 1098.72, 1456.88, 2109.34, 1987.55,        1872.36 };

            // Declair and initilize an accululator variable.
            double totals = 0;

            // Step through array adding each element
            for (int index = 0; index < units.Length; index++)
                {
                totals += units[index];
                }


            // Read the sales
            ReadSales(salesList);

            // Display Sales
            DisplaySales(salesList);

            // Display Total
            outputLabel.Text = totals.ToString();

            // Display Average Sales Cost
            averageSales = Average(salesList);
            averageCostLabel.Text = averageSales.ToString("n1");
        }







        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Close the window
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to tell your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I want to read the data into memory from the file and into memory and then sum the decimal from there so that the numerical values can be changed in the file and someone will not have to touch the code every time the numbers change.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler way to read all lines in bulk:

```
List<decimal> values = File.ReadAllLines("Sales.txt")
                           .Select(s => decimal.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                           .ToList();
```

In your code:

```
private void ReadSales(List<decimal> salesList)
{
    salesList.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("Sales.txt")
                           .Select(s => decimal.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
}
```

Comment: You could use File.ReadLines() instead to prevent loading the entire file into memory first before enumerating (if it was a very large data file), then after than you can just use the Sum() LINQ extension method.

Comment: @martin_costello Yes, you are right, but since it is a homework I wouldn't expect big file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ for that instead of the loop.

For sum:

```
decimal total = salesList.Sum()
```

For average:

```
decimal avg = salesList.Average();
```

Comment: The `s => s` here is superfluous. `salesList.Sum()` and `salesList.Average()` should suffice.

Comment: the problem is not in the loop.actual problem is about culture.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior You're absolutely right. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Selman22 What culture and what problem? He didn't mention any problem and he said he got it working. I had the impression that he was just looking for other/better ways to do things, that's all.